# yql and firebug xpath copy/paste returning no result

Tags: authentication, xpath, jira, httpresponse, yql

I'm trying to do a little bit of screenscraping of a 3rd party vendors bug tracking system (jira) where I can scrape the count/category of all the unresolved bugs.  I want to put this info on our intranet so management can see it without going to the 3rd party site (which they don't have login credentials for).

I'm having problems getting xpath results back, though.  Here's what I'm doing.  Using Firebug, I select the DOM element I'm interested in and right-click "copy as xpath".  Then I paste that into the YQL console, so I have something that looks like:

```
select * 
from html 
where url='http://username:password@jira.3rdparty.com/path/to/page_i_want.aspx'
      and xpath='//*[@id="primary"]'
```

My JSON results come back null.  If I remove the xpath in my query, I get back results.  If I select other elements on the page, my JSON results come back null.  If I start tweaking the xpath, say remove the last div in the path, I can sometimes get results, it just depends on what I've selected and what I've tweaked in the xpath.

Anyone know why I'm not getting any results doing the Firebug copy as xpath?  I can't really say I'm an xpath pro :)

**Edit:**  Actually, looking at the results I'm getting back with no xpath, it looks like I'm not authenticating.  My username has an @ and domain in it, so I log in via a browser with something like:

> username@domain
>
> password

YQL doesn't seem to like the @domain and \ escaping the @ doesn't seem to work.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as following criteria are met:

> The module will only fetch HTML pages under 1.5MB and the page must also be indexable (e.g. allowed by the site’s robots.txt file.) .

Since it is behind a login, it's probably not indexable. The `robots.txt` is public, such as:

http://internet.com/robots.txt

For future reference, use double quotes to escape the commercial-at symbol:

```
'http://"username@domain:password"@jira.3rdparty.com/path/to/page_i_want.aspx'
```

Here are some resources:

- [Pipes XPath fetch page](http://pipes.yqlblog.net/2012/04/24/new-module-xpath-fetch-page/)
- [Commercial-at Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0040/index.htm)